# How to pass resource parameter from one stack to another using aws_cdk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I'm trying to create two separate stacks for 2 resources namely lambda function and API gateway. Below is the code from my app.py

```
import aws_cdk as cdk
from Stack.lambda_function.hello_handler_stack import HelloHandlerStack
from Stack.apigateway.hello_handler_apigateway_handler import HelloHandlerApigatewayStack
app = cdk.App()

Stack1 = HelloHandlerStack(app, "HelloHandlerStack", env=cdk.Environment(Account="**",Region="*"))

Stack2 = HelloHandlerApigatewayStack(app, "HelloHandlerApigatewayStack", env=cdk.Environment(Account="**",Region="*"), temp_lambda = Stack1.my_lambda)

app.synth()
```

**hello_handler_stack.py**

```
from constructs import Construct
from aws_cdk import (
    Stack,
    aws_lambda as _lambda,
)

class HelloHandlerStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        my_lambda = _lambda.Function(
            self, 'HelloHandler',
            runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_7,
            code=_lambda.Code.from_asset('lambda'),
            handler='hello.handler',
        )
        self.my_lambda = my_lambda
```

**hello_handler_apigateway_handler.py**

```
from constructs import Construct
from aws_cdk import (
    Stack,
    aws_lambda as _lambda,
    aws_apigateway as apigw,
)


class HelloHandlerApigatewayStack(Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        apigw.LambdaRestApi(
          self, 'Endpoint',
          handler=kwargs["test_lambda"],
        )
```

But when I do cdk ls, I get an error stating

> TypeError: Stack.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument
> 'test_lambda'

I should be able to pass the keyword argument to the second stack and use it to build the api gateway, is there any other references I should provide while calling the classes?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Debugged the problem. Had to write the keyword argument in the constructor argument definition that is being passed inside the constructor call.

**hello_handler_apigateway_handler.py**

```
from constructs import Construct
from aws_cdk import (
    Stack,
    aws_lambda as _lambda,
    aws_apigateway as apigw,
)


class HelloHandlerApigatewayStack(Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, id: str, test_lambda, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)
    apigw.LambdaRestApi(
      self, 'Endpoint',
      handler=test_lambda,
    )
```